# Can a background image be larger than the div itself?

Tags: css, image, background

I have a footer div with 100% width. It's about 50px high, depending on its content.

Is it possible to give that #footer a background image that kind of overflows this div?

The image is about 800x600px, and I want it to be positioned in the left bottom corner of the footer. It should work sort of like a background image for my website, but I've already set a background image on my body. I need another image positioned at the bottom left corner of my website and the #footer div would be perfect for that.

```
#footer {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 30px 0 0;
    background:#eee url(images/bodybgbottomleft.png) no-repeat left bottom fixed;
}
```

The image is set to the footer, however it doesn't overflow the div. Is it possible to make that happen?

`overflow:visible` doesn't do the job!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I do not believe that you can make a background image overflow its div.  Images placed in Image tags can overflow their parent div, but background images are limited by the div for which they are the background.

Answer (score 202):

There is a very easy trick. Set padding of that div to a positive number and margin to negative

```
#wrapper {
    background: url(xxx.jpeg);
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I think this should be accepted answer.

Comment: Even though it makes the trick, this modifies the size of the wrapper and not extending it outside. This makes all other items which do not depend on padding reposition

Answer (score 29):

You can use a css3 psuedo element (`:before` and/or `:after`) as shown in this article

https://www.exratione.com/2011/09/how-to-overflow-a-background-image-using-css3/

Good Luck...

Comment: I prefer this method because it does not interfer with the positionning of the `#wrapper` element (like if you need to center it with `margin: 0 auto;`)

Answer (score 12):

No, you can't.

But as a solid workaround, I would suggest to classify that first div as `position:relative` and use `div::before` to create an underlying element containing your image. Classified as `position:absolute` you can move it anywhere relative to your initial div.

Don't forget to add content to that new element. Here's some example:

```
div {
  position: relative;
}    

div::before {
  content: ""; /* empty but necessary */
  position: absolute;
  background: ...
}
```

Note: if you want it to be 'on top' of the parent div, use `div::after` instead.

Comment: how does it work for you? position absolute makes element on top of every unpositioned siblings of the "before" block, i.e. the whole content of the div

Answer (score 7):

Using background-size cover worked for me.

```
#footer {
    background-color: #eee;
    background-image: url(images/bodybgbottomleft.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 30px 0 0;
}
```

Obviously be aware of support issues, check Can I Use: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Answer (score 5):

Use trasform: scale(1.1) property to make bg image bigger, move it up with position: relative; top: -10px;

```html
<div class="home-hero">
  <div class="home-hero__img"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.home-hero__img{
  position:relative;
  top:-10px;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  background: {
    size: contain;
    image: url('image.svg');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You mention already having a background image on `body`.

You *could* set that background image on `html`, and the new one on `body`. This will of course depend upon your layout, but you wouldn't need to use your footer for it.

Answer (score 2):

Not really - the background image is bounded by the element it's applied to, and the overflow properties only apply to the content (i.e. markup) within an element.

You can add another div into your footer div and apply the background image to that, though, and have that overflow instead.

Answer (score 2):

[This could help](http://jsfiddle.net/sqPmf/5/).
It requires the footer height to be a fixed number. Basically, you have a div inside the footer div with it's normal content, with `position: absolute`, and then the image with `position: relative`, a negative `z-index` so it stays "below" everything, and a negative `top` value of the footer's height minus the image height (in my example, `50px - 600px = -550px`). Tested in Chrome 8, FireFox 3.6 and IE 9.