# How to set a background image in full size of a div that doesn't fill page

Tags: css, html, background-image, image

i need to put an image in background of a div at the center position of it, like: 
[image: Example]

What i've tried is:

```
<div id="container">
    ...
</div
<div id="background">
    <img src="images/bg.png"/>
</div>
```

with this css:

```
div#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 52em;
}
div#bg img {
    z-index: -999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 22%;
}
```

In my browser, with my screen size, i put 22% and all is ok, but if i try on another screen with different size background img isn't in the center of div. What can i do? can someonehelp me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give

```
position:relative;
```

in the container div..It should work..
And the background div(with `position:absolute;`) should be a child of container div..then only u'll get the div overlapping property

Answer (score 0):

can use css as below:

```
#sample
{
    background:url(bg_apple_little.gif) no-repeat center center;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
```

& you div would be with  id="sample". 
height, width can be varied as per your requirement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280886/css-background-image-larger-than-div-itself as you can see here, a background image could not overflow a div

Comment: but it would fill only its own area as centered.

Answer (score 0):

in css3 you can use `#container {
background-size: auto;
}`