# How to display FULL background image of a div no matter if contents in div is smaller

Tags: css, background-image

I have a header image located at ink.talentosoft.com take a look if you can.

The header image is exactly 388 px in height. I want the background of this div to be fully displayed. Currently the set up for the div is as follows:

```
 background: url(http://ink.talentosoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/header.png) no-repeat 100% center;
```

Because the contents of this div is smaller than the background, the rest of the image is cut off.
How may I extend the full height of this image?

```
 background-size: 100%;//did not work
```

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280886/css-background-image-larger-than-div-itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you could do `height:388px;` for your div.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
background-size: auto 388px;
```